# Angular reading from config.json and initialize HttpClient takes too long

Tags: angular, rest, post

Instead of having my urls in the code I've placed them in config file.
and my `service.ts`

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.getServerUrlFromConfig();
    }

getServerUrlFromConfig() {
        this.http.get<any>('./assets/data/config.json')
        .subscribe(data => {
            if (!!data && !!data.confServerUrl && data.confServerUrl != '') {
                this.serverUrl = data.confServerUrl;
            }
        });
    }
```

the problem is that it takes too long and when `ngAfterViewInit()` in component.ts executes and calls a function that expects the serverUrl to be initialized its not

is there a **better/ faster** way of doing it without writting the url in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a `getServerUrlFromConfig` function, and loading up the URL in that way, one easy, fast, and baked-in method for this could be using your `environment.ts` file. Inside of each different environment, you could define the URL's there. For example, your `environment.ts` (your development environment) could have this added to it:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  api_url: 'https://my-api.com/'
};
```

Then, in your service, you would just `import` it like a regular javascript variable to use it:

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

export class Service() {
  apiURL: string = environment.apiURL;
}
```

See the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-application-environments) for the `environment.ts` file and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59928549/what-is-best-way-to-store-api-urls-and-use-in-angular) for how I got this example because the answers are so similar. In this instance, you would also be able to customize the URL per environment, which would be super nice.

Comment: the difference between a ts file and a config file is that when you make a change in ts file you must re-compile and re-deploy whereas with config you don't

Comment: Hmm.. will you be re-compiling that often? I think I'm having trouble understanding your scenario. In any scenario, when you change code, you'll have to re-deploy regardless. Are your URL's going to change that often? Are these not external API / service URL's?